# Calculus of variation: quasi convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am given the following things: let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{(N\times n)\times(N\times n)}$ be a symmetric matrix. The function $f: \mathbb{R}^{N\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as: 
$$f(\xi):=\langle M\xi, \xi \rangle.$$
I have to show:

$$f\text{ is quasi convex} \Longleftrightarrow \int_{\Omega} f (D\varphi(x)) \,dx \geq 0$$
$\forall \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded and for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_0\left(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N\right)$.

I have absolutly no idea how to start, can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: What does "quasi-convex" mean?

Comment: f is called quasi-convex, if $f \in L^\infty _{loc} (\mathbb{R}^{(N\times n)})$ and $f(\xi) \leq \frac{1}{\vert \Omega\vert} \int_{\Omega}f(x+D\varphi(x)) dx $ for all open and bounded $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{(N\times n)}$ and all $\varphi \in C^1_0 (\Omega,\mathbb{R}^N)$.

Comment: @Gustav.G, in your definition of quasi-convexity, the inequality with $f(\xi)\leq \frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int ...$, is there a connection between $\xi$ and the right-hand side of the inequality ?